# Preferred way of adding custom elements to TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce, rich-text-editor

I am new to tinyMCE and currently investigating the preferred way of adding custom elements to tinyMCE?

I added a number of buttons to the toolbar, that in turn trigger (a) the insertion of elements for selected parts of text and (b) remove those elements from selected text when clicked on again.

I do not want to allow nesting for these elements, so basically I just want to markup  parts of a sentence or word with a given, non-overlapping, tag, e.g.: `<foo>Hello</foo> world`

For the moment I found these two possibilities in the tinyMCE docs:

```
#1 tinyMCE.execInstanceCommand(editor_id, command, user_interface, value, focus)
```

and

```
#2  var n = dom.create(element);
    n.innerText = sel.getContent({format : 'text'});
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setNode(n);
```

where #2 looks like the more flexible approach and hence worth pursuing to me.

I already started implementing a plugin using approach #2, but I am unsure how I would handle stuff like:

- selections overlapping *element boundaries* and *text* nodes (like `<foo>hello</foo> world <bar>!</bar>`
- merging adjacent elements (`<foo>bar</foo><foo>bar</foo>`) or
- how to cope with *empty* elements and so on.

This is why I am wondering if I am missing some kind of predefined interface, because lots of these functionalities should as well be needed by the "normal" elements such as `strong, em, h1,…,h6` and the like.

If you need any more information let me know, any hints or pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For formatting purposes there is the `Formatter.js` class in the tinymce core files.
But what you want is pretty complicated. We tried to hinder tinymce to nest spans and tweaked `Formatter.js` to our needs.

Comment: Thanks for answer Thariama, my intention is keeping it as simple as possible :-) Would you mind sending me the corresponding code fragment(s) (only if it doesn’t cause any trouble/inconveniences)? I am trying to avoid nesting as well. I guess my main problem is, that am still looking for the "right" way & place to do it, but I will try to study Formatter.js

Comment: Unfortunatly, SO offers only limited space to be posted, so i put the class code and pasted it here: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/2tcaab  . I hope this will be of help to you.

Comment: Thank you, would you mind if I don't yet mark this as solved? Your answer helps a lot, still if there are other opinions out there I'd be glad to hear them as well :-)